# Wordpress doesn't show all posts of a specific author

Tags: author, multi-author

I'm running a multi-author wordpress. Recently I've changed username of one of my authors (using Easy Username Updater plugin, and verifying it in the database).

Now, in the frontend the author page doesn't show all of his posts (only some of them), though all of these posts can be found in the backend.

What went wrong?

Comment: Get posts usually depends on a few conditions including the post status(publish, private) and so on. So it depends on your query arguments when you try to fetch the posts. Are you using GUI to do settings or custom code to do post query?